# MVC not parsing IEnumerable values in request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 seems to be having trouble parsing the object I am sending it.

Using jQuery's ajax function, I send the data using POST request. I receive it in the Request object, it appears like this in the Request.Form:

```
{Name=Test&Groups%5b0%5d%5bName%5d=GroupName1&Groups%5b0%5d%5bCount%5d=123Groups%5b1%5d%5bName%5d=GroupName2&Groups%5b1%5d%5bCount%5d=123ID=bee4c411-f06c-43c6-815f-8002df4f2779}

//formatted for readability
Name=Test &
Groups[0][Name]=GroupName1 &
Groups[0][Count]=123 &
Groups[1][Name]=GroupName2 &
Groups[1][Count]=123 &
ID=bee4c411-f06c-43c6-815f-8002df4f2779
```

The `Name` and `ID` values are parsed just fine, but the Groups array is not... I do get an `IEnumerable`, and it contains the correct number of groups but the values within are `null`.

I've read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) and [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and I can't seem to find what I did wrong...

**What am I missing?**

The MVC `Action` looks like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateGroups(GroupsListRequest req)
{
    [...] //handle the request
}
```

and `GroupsListRequest` looks like this:

```
public class GroupsListRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupRequest> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, `GroupsRequest` looks like this:

```
public class GroupsRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your view look like? Or how do you send that object, what format is it supposed to represent?

Comment: In order to bind it would need to be `Groups[0].Name:GroupName1& ...`

Comment: @Stephen this format makes no sense, it would be `key=value`, not `key:value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

remove the square bracket around name and count field in request.

```
Name:Test &
Groups[0].Name:GroupName1 &
Groups[0].Count:123 &
Groups[1].Name:GroupName2 &
Groups[1].Count:123 &
ID:bee4c411-f06c-43c6-815f-8002df4f2779
```

your input name should be like this

```
<input type="text" name="Groups[0].Name" value="George" />
```

Comment: added some text description

Answer (score 0):

So, as @sangramparmar and @stephenmuecke mentioned, the problem was with the format of the objects in the array - they were surrounded by an extra pair of brackets.

Several circumstances made this problematic to fix:

- I am using jQuery to send the request to the server, and the `param` function is the one causing the problem by parsing the array incorrectly (at least as far as C#'s MVC is concerned
- Each request to the server needs to have a (session-constant) key added to its data prior to sending the request. This is performed automatically through a global `ajaxSetup`
- For some reason, MVC failed to read the ajax request's data when I set the `contentType` to `application/json` (at least, failed to read it in the way I was expecting... which, if I've learned anything ever, was probably misdirected in some way)

The solution I ended up using was to build my own `stringify` function to parse the data object to a string, like so:

```
stringify: function (obj, prefix) {
    var objString = '';
    prefix = prefix || '';

    if(typeof(obj) === 'object') {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            _.each(obj, function (item, index) {
                objString = objString + utilityMethods.stringify(item, prefix + '%5b' + index + '%5d');
            });
        } else {
            if (prefix != undefined && prefix.length !== 0) {
                prefix = prefix + '.';
            }
            _.each(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
                objString = objString + utilityMethods.stringify(obj[key], prefix + key);
            });
        }
    } else {
        objString = objString + '&' + prefix + '=' + obj;
    }

    return objString;
}
```

Then, in global `ajaxSetup`, I added a `beforeSend` to add the needed key, like so:

```
beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    var userKeyString = 'userKey=' + [... fetch the user key...];
    if (settings.type.toUpperCase() === 'GET') {
        settings.url = settings.url + '&' + userKeyString;
    } else {
        if (settings.data != undefined) {
            settings.data = userKeyString + '&' + settings.data;
        }
    }
},
```

**Now, I do end up with an extra ampersand in each request.** I'll fix that eventually... maybe.